Set the prefix for the default namespace
I have XML:
<root xmlns="test:env:v.1"><elem1>text-1</elem1><elem2>text-2</elem2></root>

I need to set a prefix for the default namespace using lxml:
<n1:root xmlns:n1="test:env:v.1"><n1:elem1>text-1</n1:elem1><n1:elem2>text-2</n1:elem2></n1:root>


Here is the solution: Create a new xml (wrapper) with the namespace prefix set, and put the original xml in it, the prefix will be inherited. If you want to keep the original XML, you can apply deepcopy.
import copy

from lxml import etree

origin = etree.fromstring('<root xmlns="test:env:v.1"><elem1>text-1</elem1><elem2>text-2</elem2></root>')

ns = origin.nsmap[None]
wrapper = etree.Element(etree.QName(ns, 'wrap'), nsmap={'n1': ns})

result = copy.deepcopy(origin)
wrapper.append(result)

print(etree.tostring(origin, method='c14n').decode('ascii'))
print(etree.tostring(result, method='c14n').decode('ascii'))

There may be a better solution
